# How to find the longest continuous numbers and its location?

Tags: r

I have a numeric vectors as following.

```
V1 <- c(1:3, 7:20, 23,45,55,27:30, 66, 88:89)
```

How can I find the longest continuous sequence and the location? In this case, the length of the target sequence is `14` and the location is `18`
Please advise

My ugly is to use `which` and `shift`

```
V1 <- c(1:3, 7:20, 23,45,55,27:30, 66, 88:89)
V2 <- c(1, which(V1-shift(V1)!=1)
max(V2-shift(V2, fill =0))
```

But I can't find the location of `18`

Comment: Isn't the location 4, not 18? The longest consecutive sequence is 7:20, starting at index 4.

Comment: yes, starts at 4, and ends at 18

Comment: Oh, location is end, not start, got it. The 18th element is 23 though, so I think the end should be 17 right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rle` on `diff` of `V1`

```
x <- rle(diff(V1))

#To get the length of longest sequence we can do
max(x$lengths) + 1
#[1] 14

#To get the end index of longest sequence
sum(x$lengths[seq_len(which.max(x$lengths))]) + 1
#[1] 17
```

Comment: Thanks, it's my first contact of `rle`

Answer (score 3):

We get the difference of adjacent elements with `diff` and if we need to `split` the `vector`, create a logical condition with `cumsum` and then get the `max` of the `lengths` of `list` elements

```
lst1 <- split(seq_along(V1), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(V1) != 1)))
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
mx
#[1] 14
tail(lst1[[match(mx, lengths(lst1))]], 1)
#[1] 17
```

---

Of if we are only interested in the `max` `length`

```
max(diff(which(diff(V1) != 1)))
#[1] 14
```

Or another option is `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
max(tabulate(rleid(diff(V1)))) + 1
#[1] 14
```

---

The whole thing can be done in a single line

```
data.table(V1)[, .(n = .N + 1, .I), .(grp = rleid(c(1, diff(V1))))
       ][n == max(n), .SD[.N]]
#  grp  n  I
#1:   3 14 17
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `diff` to identify consecutive sequential numbers and then group values of the diff with `rleid`. After grouping I use `.N` to get the length and `.I` to get the starting and ending index.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(V1)[, dV1 := c(diff(V1), NA)]
df[, .(len = .N + 1, start = first(.I), end = last(.I) + 1), by = .(dV1, g = rleid(dV1))
   ][which.max(len*(dV1 == 1)), .(len, start, end)]

#    len start end
# 1:  14     4  17
```

Validation

```
V1[4:17]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```